# Can I define scenarios for Google Play UI tests?

Tags: android, google-play, automated-tests

When I deploy my application on Google Play Beta environment I see that Google runs tests on it.

After tests I see report like this

[image]

When I look to screenshots I realize that scenarios are random, it seems that robots clicks all buttons in application randomly and type random text to inputs.

Can more intelligent scenarios be defined?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is actually its own product: [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/). With it, you can run instrumentation tests as well as the crawler tests you've seen.